# Getting: error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected. In ReactJS & TypeScript app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Here is my current code for the new component I created which is causing this error to be throw.

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/components/Hello.tsx
> (5,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

I've checked other answers and haven't found the actual issue yet.

```
// src/components/Hello.tsx

import * as React from 'react';

export Interface Props {
  name: string;
  enthusiasmLevel?: number;
}

function Hello({ name, enthusiasmLevel = 1 }: Props) {
  if (enthusiasmLevel <= 0) {
    throw new Error('You could be a little more enthusiastic. :D');
  }

  return (
    <div className="hello">
      <div className="greeting">
        Hello {name + getExclamationMarks(enthusiasmLevel)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Hello;

// helpers

function getExclamationMarks(numChars: number) {
  return Array(numChars + 1).join('!');
}
```

Comment: `Interface` --> `interface` (it should be lowercase)

Comment: I actually had an error which asked me to make it uppercase, however I just realized the error. After I changed my tslint file, I forgot to re-start yarn. I'll close this soon, since this isn't a logic based problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
export Interface Props {
```

to

```
export interface Props {
```